# How to parse a Date and Time, separately, into a DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm trying to parse two separate fields, a date and a time, into one DateTime object as strings. The date has padding, the time doesn't, but they follow a consistent format, with date being something like `07302018` and time being `101230`; an issue being, as well, that time could be something like `91230`. What I've tried right now:

```
string timeformat1 = "MMddyyyy HHmmss";
string timeformat2 = "MMddyyyy Hmmss";
string date = "07302018"
string time = "63020"


if (time.Length == 6)
   {
      datetimeobject = DateTime.ParseExact($"{date} {time}", timeformat1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
else
   {
      datetimeobject = DateTime.ParseExact($"{date} {time}", timeformat2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
```

Doesn't seem to work, giving a "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" exception.

Am I going to need to insert some slashes and punctuation into the strings in order to make them read correctly? I wanted to avoid this because I had heard there are performance concerns with disassembling and reassembling strings, but I may have to do so unless there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Whata are the values of `date` and `time`?

Comment: Sorry, they're in the format specified in the strings above. With date being something like `20180730` and time being `101230`; the issue being, as well, that time could be something like `91230`.

Comment: I am not sure why you think `20180730` fits `MMddyyyy`, it's more like `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: well, then your format is wrong, it should be `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not sure either. Thank you for auditing my brain.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto however, I still receive the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Also note that a single `H` match both `9` and `10`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Please update the question with actual values for `date` and `time`

Comment: @Magnetron Thank you, I also changed that, but still having the same problem.

Comment: @Archer I added some sample date and times. They're coming from a database en masse, so they can be either format, which is the issue.

Comment: In the example you've given, `time` is 5 characters long so it should fit `format2`, but you're using `format1`.

Comment: I see you're checking for the length of time to see if it is `== 7`. Are you including the space before it because the maximum length I can see happening according to your format is 6

Comment: Now in the question your date is in format `MMddyyyy` and your format `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: It works perfectly when you get rid of all the errors that keep cropping up in your code.  Just take some time to make sure your logic is correct and that you use the correct format.  Here -> **https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Rmx5p**

Comment: Okay, I apologize. It is now fixed to the correct format. The issue was that I specified it incorrectly at the beginning. I deserve the downvotes for being this airheaded right now, but thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: It's still wrong.  `if (time.Length == 6) { // use the format with a 5 figure time }`.  You're not paying attention - that's all that's wrong with your code.

Comment: @Archer I switched it to avoid the if's altogether, since it was pointed out that H can be either 1 or 2 digits, but I'm still receiving the same error at the same place.

Comment: Did you see the link I posted in a previous comment?  There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, in principle.  I don't think you can parse a time with `Hmmss` - it needs a 2 figure hour

Comment: The one H did not work, you're right. Thank you all for your help. I should probably screw my head on before asking a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to avoid ifs

```
string timeformat = "MMddyyyy HHmmss";

string date = "07302018";
string time = "91230";
string joint = $"{date} {time.PadLeft(6,'0')}";
DateTime datetimeobject = DateTime.ParseExact(joint, timeformat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `DateTime.ParseExact` will fail with a single char for hour and the single `H` because it need a separation between hour and other values. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or
>   time separators (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to get it working without either doing the PadLeft or the ifs, but this worked. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks, even though my question was kind of a trainwreck I still learned a lot about DateTime and now string.PadLeft as well.

Comment: @nostalgk you're welcome. There is also `PadRight` that fills to the right instead of to the left.

Comment: @Magnetron Seeing as my time is going to be variably either 5 or 6, does PadLeft work like an if statement in that if the str.length is the specified amount, it won't change it?

Comment: @nostalgk yes, it'll fill the string until it reaches the amout of chars that you specified in the first argument

Comment: @nostalgk Check it's [reference page in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0), in special, the return value description